# Finding width of each line in richtextbox where wordwrap is true

Tags: vb.net

I have a `richtextbox` and i have put a long sentences. Its `wordwrap` is on. Because of this it shows 4 lines. I want to show the width of each line separately.

I have tried with `richtextbox1.lines.length`, but it is showing: 1

[image]

Comment: In characters or words?

Comment: The `Lines` property has no awareness of word-wrap. It is based on line breaks in the text only. The `RichTextBox` has a bunch of methods that respect word-wrap, e.g. `GetLineFromCharIndex`, that you can use to get the information you want. Basically, you'll have to loop through characters indexes and call that method to see where the line number changes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm also trying to split the lines RichTextBox1.Lines(index) (index = 0 To GetLineFromCharIndex value of text) but argument overloading for .Lines() isn't allowed, I'm stuck there.

Comment: `Lines` is useless to you. Stop trying to use it.

Comment: What will you do with this information when you know it?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code briefly and I think that it does what you want. It will include carriage return and line break characters in the count I think, so you will have to handle that explicitly if you need different.

```
Dim previousFirstCharIndex = 0
Dim lineIndex = 1
Dim firstCharIndex = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex)
Dim lineLengths As New List(Of Integer)

Do Until firstCharIndex = -1
    lineLengths.Add(firstCharIndex - previousFirstCharIndex)
    previousFirstCharIndex = firstCharIndex

    lineIndex += 1
    firstCharIndex = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex)
Loop

lineLengths.Add(RichTextBox1.TextLength - previousFirstCharIndex)

MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lineLengths), "Line Lengths")
```

Comment: but i want to print width of each line just right side of richtext box after each line. is it possible?